# Simple chrome extension for GMAIL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, gmail, gmail-api

I'm new to programming.I started learning python about 2 months ago to automate some of the emailing for my job,as we don't have a reliable auto-emailing.With lots of effort and searching on the internet,i succeded.

Now i started learning javascript with the purpose to create a chrome extension,it would do the following thing:

**When you put some email addresses on the bcc field,send the e-mail to all those people individually,instead of blind carbon copy.It would be the equivalent of send the e-mail to all those people 1 by 1 with their email in the "to" field.**

The problem is i'm very inexperienced and i don't even know what i need to use to do this,the gmail api or the gadgets api?

I have been reading for some days and the google api guides aren't very clear about how to create extensions for chrome.

Also,i tried the GMAIl API javascript quickstart,but the python web server gives me an error.

**I would be very grateful if someone could give me directions on how to do it.**

Thank you all!

Comment: Are you not sure how to send email with javascript? I couldn't understand which part(s) you need help.

Comment: I don't want to send emails with javascript,i'm already doing that with python.I just want the extension to change what the bcc field does when i'm sending an email.Iwht python was much easier because all the message was written in code.I dont know how to do it in javascript because i need a part of something that's already done changed.